# is this a good approach to automate opening cmd line and run a tool and return results python 3.6

Tags: python, cmd, automation

EDITED:
I found the solution by looking at the length of the return output as shown below

```
 try:
                exitcode, output = subprocess.getstatusoutput(command)
                print(exitcode)
                if exitcode == 0:
                    print("INFO : XSSStrike tool is running successfully ...")
                if len(output) == 32:
                    print('XSS injection check : \' results:\'   \'' "None" '\'' + \
                          ' ... [ ' + self.OKGREEN + 'OK' + self.endColor + ' ]')
                else:
                    print(
                        'XSS injection check : \' results:\'   \''" found vulnerable pages to xss injection "  '\'' + \
                        ' ... [ ' + self.WARNING + 'WARN' + self.endColor + ' ]')
                    self.nm_of_fails += 1
                    print(str(output))
```

I'm using this method to automate 
- navigate to a giving tool path
- read JSON config file
- get results from the tool 
- evaluate results

this a snip from the method where I use subprocess to run cmd command, this command has parameters for the tool to filter console output that is being return to  (tooloutput = subprocess.getoutput(command))

```py
depth = value["crawl-depth"]
if self.cookie == '':
    command = "cd " + tool_path + " && python xsstrike.py -u " + url + " --params --crawl -l " + depth + " --skip --blind --file-log-level VULN --console-log-level VULN --log-file " + formatName
else:
    cookie_para = f'"cookie:{self.cookie}"'
    command = "cd " + tool_path + " && python xsstrike.py -u " + url + " --header " + cookie_para + " --params --crawl -l " + depth + " --skip --blind --file-log-level VULN --console-log-level VULN --log-file " + formatName

tooloutput = subprocess.getoutput(command)

if len(tooloutput) != 0:
    print("INFO: XSSStrike TOOL FULL RESULTS: " + tooloutput)
else:
    print("no results ")
```

why the length of toolouput is none? 
when the tool is finished, is the subprocess killed automatically?

Comment: We can't help you about the missing output without knowing what the called program does/is. Please [edit] your question to provide a *minimal* reproducible example – see [ask] for details. Are you aware that Python has [builtin support to change the current directory](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.chdir)?

Answer (score 0):

The following steps might help you to resolve your issue.

1. Try to run each of your commands manually through the command line
   to see if there is an output.
2. Confirm also that 'command' contains the string that you need to
       execute prior to running subprocess.getoutput(command).

Comment: I have fixed, by looking at the length of the return string for no results return length of 32 , while with results is bigger than 32